# Is a partition of the empty set defined or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Definition** A *partition* $\Pi$ of a set $A$ is a set of nonempty subsets of $A$ that is disjoint and exhaustive, i.e.,
> (a) no two different sets in $\Pi$ have any common elements, and
> (b) each element of $A$ is in some set in $\Pi$

This definition doesn't explicitly say $A$ is nonempty. And to me this is interpreted in two ways.

1. "nonempty subsets of $A$" implies $A$ is nonempty.
2. When $A$ is the empty set some kind of vacuous true occurs(I can't make a precise argument but it seems). So empty set has a partition(but if so, what is a partition of $\emptyset$?).

Comment: Does the empty set have a nonempty subset?

Comment: Technically, the set of nonempty subsets of the empty set is again the empty set , so you could consider the empty set to be a partition of itself. But it does not really make sense.

Comment: @Peter The empty set _is_ a partition of itself - why doesn't that make sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's true that the emptyset as no non-empty subsets. Curiously this does *not* imply that there is no partition of $\emptyset$.

> > $\emptyset$ is a partition of $\emptyset$.

Note that every element of $\emptyset$ is a non-empty subset of $\emptyset$, vacuously. The (non-existent) elements are pairwise disjoint and have union equal to $\emptyset$, qed.